# What does ":op?" mean in a url route?

Tags: javascript, express, url-routing

Looking at some Node.js Express code, I see this route list:

```
app.all('/user/:id/:op?', user.load);
app.get('/user/:id', user.view);
app.get('/user/:id/view', user.view);
app.get('/user/:id/edit', user.edit);
app.put('/user/:id/edit', user.update);
```

When running this, I notice that requests for `/user/:id` actually get routed to `user.load`. Being new to this, I was surprised.

What does the `:op?` do in the first line that causes it to catch a less specific route? I couldn't find any instance of `:op?` in the [Express documentation](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html).

Comment: It's a variable, it could be anything

Comment: When url is `/user/120/hello`, `op` will be `hello`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation of [`app.all`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.all):

> This method is extremely useful for mapping "global" logic for
>   specific path prefixes or arbitrary matches.

Now lets have a look at the routing.

Question mark `?` in `app.all('/user/:id/:op?', user.load)` means that the parameter `:op` (can be considered as *"operation"*) in the route is optional.

As the `all` method call is placed before other route calls, everything that matches the routes `/user/:id/`, `/user/:id/view`, and `/user/:id/edit` will first pass through the `user.load` method. It is worth to mention, that `:op` as a parameter most probably doesn't play any specific role in `user.load` but works as a placeholder in the route.

Most probably this approach helps to check if the entity exists in the database before continuing with `view` or `edit` operations.

Also, keeping in mind [@apsillers comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24515069/what-does-op-mean-in-a-url-route/#comment37955575_24515194) and the referred citation from the docs, `user.load` method might have a `next()` call in the end of the callback in order to progress with the other route matches.

Comment: From a few sentences later in the `app.all` docs (which might help further clarify your answer if the OP isn't familiar with Express): "Keep in mind that these callbacks do not have to act as end points, `loadUser` can perform a task, then `next()` to continue matching subsequent routes." So, a single HTTP request can trigger *both* the `user.load` from `app.all` *and* another, more specific match as well immediately after. Such a strategy is already present in your answer; I just wanted to call it out explicitly.

Comment: @apsillers Thank you! I was right about to mention about this in the answer, so your comment was perfectly valid and in time.

Answer (score 0):

I have absolutely no idea what this code is, or what it does.

But I would guess that, just as `:id` is used to placehold the ID of the user, `:op?` would be used to optionally (`?`) placehold an *op*eration (such as the `view` or `edit` ones we see below it)

Comment: Have you ever played with Express?

Comment: @VisioN Nope. Never even heard of it.